# Getting all the values of a programmatically binded check box list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, checkbox

I have a check box list which is programmatically bound to a data source with the `DataValueField` as `"Id"` and `DataTextField` as `"Speciality".`

The aim is to make users check at least one `speciality` (or more than one) whose `ID` is then saved into the database.

The problem is that if a user checked more than one, the system is only picking just one of the checked `IDs`.

How do I get all the IDs of the checked check boxes? I am using `LINQ2SQL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793108/how-to-set-multiple-selected-values-in-asp-net-checkboxlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `SelectedItems` to find the checked ones? Thats not what you want. You should use the Items property and use a LINQ expression to loop through it to find the checked ones.

```
var Values = CheckBoxList.Items
        .Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(l => l.Selected)
        .Select(i => int.parse(i.Value));
```

Comment: @shit - Great!  You can cast it into a 32 bit integer, and that should have no issues going into your table.  I'll edit my answer to have some sample code for you.

Comment: @ShittuOlugbenga I'm glad to help. It's good practice to mark the best answer as accepted if you found it satisfactory. And sorry for my unfortunate misspelling of your name in my earlier reply!

Comment: Basically, u've not misspelled my name, you just added a new dimension to it. I really appreciate your concern. i think you will be a good friend. Thanks alot.

Comment: I still need a little help please. I converted the code u gave me an array of system.int[]. I made the column in the database of type sql_variant. When i tried saving into the column i get this error: **No mapping exists from object type System.Int32[] to a known managed provider native type**. What do i do now? It's urgent please.

Comment: @ShittuOlugbenga It looks like you are trying to submit the int array into a column directly.  When submitting to the DB, you should either insert each Speciality as a separate row (usually correct) or a comma delimited list (in rare cases if that's what you want).  But right now it seems you're trying to insert the array directly.

Comment: Yes! that was what i was trying to do. But i now know it was the wrong thing to do. Can u please give me a sample code for each of the two cases you just mentioned above. Please include your suggested data type for the column in the database. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
int temp=0;
var checkIds= yourCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where (li =>li.Selected && int.TryParse(li.Value,out temp))
        .Select (s=>temp);
```

Comment: Thanks, your code does want i wanted. @msigman How can i save the selected IDs in d database? I am supposed to save these IDs into a another table that had been related to the table containing the item. For example, imagine you have an EmployeeTable with DepartmentId column which is related to the ID column of DepartmentTable. The problem now is that they are all of type "long". I'm only generating InvalidCastException exception. I tried converting to int64.