# asp .net how to recreate page controls after event is fired

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, events, handler

I'm experiencing a problem for which I have been unable to find a reasonable solution.
I have provided an extremely simplified compilable example below which demonstrates the exact issue I am having.

I'll break down the workflow into bullet points.

I have some information in a database which is used to dynamically generate controls on a page

There is a delete button added beside each control

Each delete button has a click event handler attached

When the delete button is clicked it will remove the control from the database and redraw the updated list of controls

I read a post here which describes a reasonable solution to this problem: [How to update page data after event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780684/how-to-update-page-data-after-event-handling).
For whatever reason it's not working in my particular situation.

Here is my sample aspx file and code behind respectively.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PageContent"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub WebForm1_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        BindData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindData()
        PageContent.Controls.Clear()
        For Each field In ReadFromDB()
            'add delete button
            Dim delete As New LinkButton With {.Text = "[x]", .CommandArgument = field}
            AddHandler delete.Click, AddressOf DeleteItem
            PageContent.Controls.Add(delete)
            'add control
            PageContent.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = field})
            PageContent.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteItem(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
        If btn IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim itemToDelete = btn.CommandArgument
            Dim newItems = From item In ReadFromDB() Where item <> itemToDelete
            SaveToDB(newItems)
            BindData()
        End If
    End Sub


    ' stupid simple mock database for example purposes
    Private Function ReadFromDB() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim obj = TryCast(Session("Options"), IEnumerable(Of String))
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            ' defaults db values
            obj = New List(Of String) From {"Foo", "Bar", "Jar", "Car", "Par", "Tar"}
            Session("Options") = obj
        End If
        Return obj
    End Function

    Private Sub SaveToDB(items As IEnumerable(Of String))
        Session("Options") = items
    End Sub

End Class
```

What happens in the code above is, the first time a delete button is clicked, the event handler fires, removes the item from the DB and redraws the controls, everything works as expected. The next time a delete button is clicked a postback occurs but the DeleteItem event is not fired. If I click the delete button again it works.

My observation is whenever BindData is called within DeleteItem the event handlers are not called the next time a Delete button is pressed.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated. Besides doing a redirect in the DeleteItme event handler I am out of ideas about how to approach this problem.

Comment: You will need to include the html

Comment: I've added the aspx file

Comment: Try AutoEventWireup="true"

Comment: AutoEventWireup="true" did not make a difference.

Comment: @mrpringle - any solution you found? Even I feel the code is correct.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. I will have to put a redirect in the event handler for now because I really do not know what else to try.

Comment: okies. I will also check from my side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

When you create dynamic link button try to associate an ID to it too. That's the only missing part.

Something like this in your BindData:

```
Dim delete As New LinkButton With {.Text = "[x]", .ID = field, .CommandArgument = field}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Justin, you've made my weekend!

Comment: Very happy to hear that! Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be good except just one thing. The function BindData() is called two times for each post request send to server. Instead of calling it in Init event, try calling it in Load event and make sure it it called only for fresh requests i.e. when Page.IsPostBack is false.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. The page renders correctly when it is first loaded but when delete is clicked a postback occurs, BindData is not called this time, the linkbuttons and events are not created and as a result the DeleteItem event is not triggered.